# tf.keras.BatchNormalization giving unexpected output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, batch-normalization

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

print(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(tf.convert_to_tensor([[5.0, 70.0], [5.0, 60.0]])))
print(tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(tf.convert_to_tensor([[5.0, 70.0], [5.0, 60.0]])))"
```

The output of the above code (in Tensorflow 1.15) is:

```
tf.Tensor([[ 4.99 69.96] [ 4.99 59.97]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[ 0. 0.99998] [ 0. -0.99998]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
```

My problem is why the same function is giving completely different outputs. I also played with some of the parameters of the functions but the result was the same. For me, the second output is what I want. Also, pytorch's batchnorm also gives the same output as second one. So I'm thinking its the issue with keras.

Know how to fix batchnorm in keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch Normalization layer has different behavior in training vs. inferencing:

1. **During training** (i.e. when using `fit()` or when calling the layer/model with the argument `training=True`), the layer normalizes its output using the mean and standard deviation of the current batch of inputs.
2. **During inference** (i.e. when using `evaluate()` or `predict()` or when calling the layer/model with the argument `training=False` (**which is the default**), the layer normalizes its output using a moving average of the mean and standard deviation of the batches it has seen during training.

So, the first result is due to default `training=False` and the second is due to default `is_training=True`.

If you want the same result you may try:

```
x = tf.convert_to_tensor([[5.0, 70.0], [5.0, 60.0]])
print(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x, training=True).numpy().tolist())
print(tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(x).numpy().tolist())
#output
#[[0.0, 0.9999799728393555], [0.0, -0.9999799728393555]]
#[[0.0, 0.9999799728393555], [0.0, -0.9999799728393555]]
```

or

```
x = tf.convert_to_tensor([[5.0, 70.0], [5.0, 60.0]])
print(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x).numpy().tolist())
print(tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(x, is_training=False).numpy().tolist())
#output
#[[4.997501850128174, 69.96502685546875], [4.997501850128174, 59.97002410888672]]
#[[4.997501850128174, 69.96502685546875], [4.997501850128174, 59.97002410888672]]
```